# Connect Drum Hose To Washing Machine

Tags: washing-machine

I disconnected my drum hose from my washing machine to clean it out, and now I am unable to get it re-connected.  Can someone give some guidance on how to do this?

I have a Maytag front-loader Model - MHW6000XW0 Serial - C04452345 - and this is an image of the hose I am referencing[image]

**EDIT**
I have pushed the clamp down on the wide mouth side, and connected it to the drum drain, then pulled the clamp back up around the hose so it will remain in place.  I must have done something incorrectly as when the washer begins the drain cycle, water spills over the top of the hose (almost like the clamp isn't in the proper place, or the hose isn't properly fitted on) and fills the inside of the washer and seeps out into the floor.

I wanted to check and see if there was a set way of connecting the hose, or if I am just putting the clamp back up in the incorrect position or what am I missing here?

Comment: How did you disconnect it? Did it just pull off? Were there clamps that you had to release? The big end on the left looks like it screws on, did you unscrew that part? To me, it looks like you screw the big end from the left on, then insert the little end into something else, or insert something else into that little end. Either way, once the little end connection is made, it looks like it's held in place with a hose clamp.

Comment: This was a stock image I found online.  I've connected the big end to the washer drum drain, and pulled the clamp up to lock it into place.  But when the washer begins to drain, water comes up over the sides of the hose and leaks into the housing of the washer.

Comment: I'm quite aware that this is a stock image. Your original question didn't indicate that you'd tried & failed. Please [edit] your original question to provide the details that I've asked for in my previous comment, you may also want to include the rather _important_ detail about having tried & failed to get it connected. It might be helpful to see a picture of _your_ actual installation - someone may be able to spot an error that's not obvious to you. Remember all we know is exactly what you tell us. We can't see what you've done, so you _have_ to tell us or we can't be of much help.

Comment: My apalogy - I have edited my ? with the additional info